# How to pass token to ArcGis MapServer from Openlayers ImageArcGisRest

Tags: openlayers, arcgis-server

I am trying to use Openlayers ImageArcGisRest to add layers on a openlayers map from ArcGis Map Server. I have to pass a token in to the function as the application uses token authentication.

I've found that the map loads fine if I log into the map server first. It also returns the data when I use Postman with the token, so I know the token is fine. It seems to break when I try to give it a token, I think it is to do with my syntax. I have other layers to that work fine so I know its not the setting up of the map code later on.

```
var token = _my_token;
 var url =`http://myserver.com/webadaptor/rest/services/MyMapName/MapServer?token=`+token;
 this.baselayers =
   new ImageLayer({
     source: new ImageArcGISRest({
       ratio: 1,
       params: {
         LAYERS: this.visibleMapIds //("show:1,2,3")
       },
       url: url
    })
  });
```

I have also tried:

```
var token = my_token;
 var url =`http://myserver.com/webadaptor/rest/services/MyMapName/MapServer/`;
this.baselayers =
      new ImageLayer({
        source: new ImageArcGISRest({
          ratio: 1,
          params: {
            token: my_token,
            LAYERS: this.visibleMapIds //("show:1,2,3")
          },
        url: url
      })
});
```

I received this error when I try to run either option:
"Assertion failed. See https://openlayers.org/en/v5.3.0/doc/errors/#50 for details."

I really just need to know how you pass the token but ArcGis's documentation isn't the most helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was just a syntax error. The below code works fine:

```
var token = my_token;
var url =`http://myserver.com/webadaptor/rest/services/MyMapName/MapServer/`;
this.baselayers =
  new ImageLayer({
    source: new ImageArcGISRest({
      ratio: 1,
      params: {
        TOKEN: my_token,
        LAYERS: this.visibleMapIds //("show:1,2,3")
      },
    url: url
  })
});
```